# multiply columns, add with filter in power bi dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, weighted

I have the following table:

```
field | category | count | weight
---------------------------------
fname | valid    |  23   |   2
fname | invalid  |  16   |   2
mname | valid    |  18   |   1
lname | valid    |   5   |   2
addre | valid    |  15   |   1
```

I initially have the following dax that adds up all counts whose category (status) is equal to 'valid' divided by the sum of all

numerator = sum of all counts where category = valid
denominator = sum of all counts

```
VAR numerator = CALCULATE(
        SUM(table[count]),
        table[category] = "valid"
    )
VAR denominator= CALCULATE (
        SUM ( table[count]  )
    )
VAR ratio = numerator/denominator
```

above dax calculates all as single weight.

However, I need to multiply by a weight

numerator = (count * weight) and get the sum of all product where category is valid

denominator = sum of all (count * weight)

weight is constant 1 or 2, depending on the field, like fname and lname is by 2 while mname is only by 1.

I initially had

```
VAR numerator= SUMX (
        CALCULATE(table[count] * table[Weight] ),
        table[category] = "valid"
    )
VAR denominator= CALCULATE (
        SUM ( table[count] * table[Weight] )
    )
VAR ratio = numerator/denominator
```

getting parameter error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
VAR numerator = CALCULATE(
        SUMX('Table', 'Table'[count] *'Table'[weight]) ,
        'Table'[category] = "valid"
    )
VAR denominator= 
        SUMX ('Table', 'Table'[count] * 'Table'[weight] 
    )
RETURN numerator / denominator
```